# CakePHP 3: How to add a line break to Paginator sort links

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, paginator

I have a couple of columns on an index page where I would like to include line breaks.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('name') ?></th>
    <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('temp', ['label' => 'Temperature (C)']) ?></th>
    <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('vol', ['label' => 'Volume (m^3)']) ?></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

What I would like is for the column "units" to be underneath the "unit name". Essentially, I want to replace the space before the units with a "**br**" tag.

Ideally, these "**th**" items should render out similar to the following:

```
<th>Temperature<br>(C)</th>
<th>Volume<br>(m^3)</th>
```

Recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done like so:

```
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('temp', 'Temperature<br>(C)', ['escape' => false]) ?>
```

See [the documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#creating-sort-links) for an example on using html in sort links.

Comment: Perfect! I knew that I was missing something simple there. Oddly, I think that I read that last week.

Thanks.